# WHERE clause needs to be from variable or text box

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need the "WHERE" to come from a variable or text box and I am having a hard time successfully replacing 'IN PRODUCTION' with the variable or text box.

Can someone please assist me?

```
Private da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Node as 'Node', BrandName as 'Make', ipaddress as 'IP Address', AssetNumber as 'Asset Number', AreaUsed as 'Location', " & "EthernetPortQtas 'Total Ethernet Ports', SfpPortQty as 'Total SFP Ports', EthernetPortsAvail as 'Total Ethernet Ports Available', " &
                                 "SfpPortsAvail as 'Total SFP Ports Available', PortUsedForUplink as 'Ethernet Port Used For Uplink', UplinkConnectionID as 'Uplink Iternal ID', " &
                                 "UplinkArea as 'Uplink Area', UplinkHome as 'Uplink Home', UplinkHomePanelandPosition as 'Uplink Home Panel and Position', " &
                                 "UplinkHomeSwitch as 'Uplink Home Switch', UplinkHomeSwitchPort as 'Uplink Home Switch Port', " &
                                 "LastVerifiedDate as 'Date Last Verified', LastVerifiedBy as 'Verified By', Status as 'Appliance Status' FROM tbl_Switches WHERE Status = 'IN PRODUCTION' ORDER BY Node", cs)
```

Comment: First thing, use the preview window and formatting toolbar to make code look like code.  Then use Parameters to supply the data for INSERTS, UPDATES and WHERE clauses

Answer (score 1):

I am used to using command objects. So…

```
Private strSQL As String = "some connection string"
    Private Sub GetSomeData()
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(strSQL)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand With {
            .Connection = cn,
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            .CommandText = "Select Node as 'Node'...Where Status = @Status"}
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "Status").Value = cbStatus.Text ‘combo box text
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Get the parameter information form the column definition in the table. If you use a text box you will have to do a lot of checking to prevent malicious injection. Using parameters helps but you can use a combo box’s DropDownStyle set to DropDownList to limit the users input.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a suggestion in regards to Plutonix's suggestion (which I agree with) about formatting your SQL.

For example, you can completely eliminate string concatenation altogether. The following takes advantage of xml literals (one nice thing C# doesn't have).

All the code below is doing is showing how to avoid string concatenation and believe from doing this I found a malformed SELECT statement as an "as"  shown below doesn't look right.

EthernetPortQt**as** 'Total Ethernet Ports'

```
Option Strict On
'
' I favor Infer On but suggest it off if you don't understand it
'
Option Infer Off

Public Class SampleDataOperation
    Public Sub CallDemo()
        Demo("IN PRODUCTION")
    End Sub
    Public Sub Demo(ByVal pWhereValue As String)
        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "TODO"}
            Dim SelectStatement As String =
                <SQL>
                    SELECT 
                        Node as 'Node', 
                        BrandName as 'Make', 
                        ipaddress as 'IP Address', 
                        AssetNumber as 'Asset Number', 
                        AreaUsed as 'Location',
                        EthernetPortQt as 'Total Ethernet Ports', 
                        SfpPortQty as 'Total SFP Ports', 
                        EthernetPortsAvail as 'Total Ethernet Ports Available',
                        SfpPortsAvail as 'Total SFP Ports Available', 
                        PortUsedForUplink as 'Ethernet Port Used For Uplink', 
                        UplinkConnectionID as 'Uplink Iternal ID', 
                        UplinkArea as 'Uplink Area', 
                        UplinkHome as 'Uplink Home', 
                        UplinkHomePanelandPosition as 'Uplink Home Panel and Position', 
                        UplinkHomeSwitch as 'Uplink Home Switch', 
                        UplinkHomeSwitchPort as 'Uplink Home Switch Port', 
                        LastVerifiedDate as 'Date Last Verified', 
                        LastVerifiedBy as 'Verified By', 
                        Status as 'Appliance Status' 
                    FROM tbl_Switches 
                        WHERE Status = @StatusCondition
                    ORDER BY Node
                </SQL>.Value

            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With {.CommandText = SelectStatement}

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusCondition", pWhereValue)

                Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                '
                ' continue...
                '
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```